# Why can't I check this radio button using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here are my radio buttons:

```
<input type="radio" name="coolSwitch" value="0">Off
<input type="radio" name="coolSwitch" value="1">On
```

When I load the page, the second button is already clicked. I want to run JS to check the first one. Here's my JS:

```
$('input[type="radio"][name="heatSwitch"]')[0].prop('checked',true);
```

But I get this error: `$(...)[0].prop is not a function(…)`

Why?

Comment: Just a pointer. Name in html is *coolSwitch* and in js is *heatSwitch*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you are accessing the DOM element with an index of `0` in the [jQuery object](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/). You can't use jQuery methods on native DOM elements, which is why you're seeing an error.

Use the [`.eq()` method](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) to get a [jQuery object](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/) (rather than a DOM element) by its index:

```
$('input[type="radio"][name="heatSwitch"]').eq(0).prop('checked', true);
```

As a side note, it's worth mentioning that you don't even have to use the `.prop()` method. If you're accessing a DOM element, just modify the `checked` property directly:

```
$('input[type="radio"][name="heatSwitch"]')[0].checked = true;
```

or without jQuery:

```
document.querySelector('input[type="radio"][name="heatSwitch"]').checked = true;
```